# HTML onclick doesn't trigger function

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<html>
<title>Register</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sha512.js"></script>
<script>
function formhash(form, password, confirm_password) {
    if(password.value==confirm_password.value){
        var p = document.createElement("input");
        p.name = "p";
        p.type = "hidden";
        p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
        password.value = "";
        form.appendChild(p);    
        form.submit;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        header('Location: ./register.php?error=1');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="process_register.php" method="post" name="register_form">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"/></br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/></br>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password"/></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="return formhash(this.form, this.form.password, this.form.confirm_password);"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi all, I'm relatively new to web coding. I'm trying to do a registration page, but the onclick doesn't trigger the formhash function at all. Can anybody enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the JavaScript console to see if any errors are being thrown?

Comment: The purpose of `form.submit;` is....? And what is `header()`?

Comment: `header('Location: ./register.php?error=1');` is PHP not JavaScript. You should use `window.location.href = './register.php?error=1';`

Comment: Thanks Robbert, that did the job. I was mixing php in and out, didn't realize this simple mistake.

Answer (score 2):

****Don't** use inline event listeners.** This is what I have learned over the past months. 
Try these:

1. Give the Submit button an ID (id ="sumitbbutton")  or whatever.
2. Use this code to check for clicks: document.getElementById("submitbutton").onclick = thyfunction()

Check the JS console (hit f12 in chrome) and see if any errors are being thrown, and post them here.

The "return" may also be messing up the code.

I'm not the best at Js, but that's all I know. Hope it helps :)

P.S. Try Checking @Robbert 's comment.